# How to avoid repatation of code in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

Using JQuery is there away to shorten this code instead of repeating it for each new control?

```
//input control_1
    $("#control_1").click(function() {
            $("#control_1").addClass("CellInput");
            $("#control_1").removeClass("CellInput_");
        }); 
            
        $("#control_1").focusout(function() {
            $("#control_1").removeClass("CellInput");
            $("#control_1").addClass("CellInput_");   
        });

//input control_2
    $("#control_2").click(function() {
            $("#control_2").addClass("CellInput");
            $("#control_2").removeClass("CellInput_");
        }); 
            
        $("#control_2").focusout(function() {
            $("#control_2").removeClass("CellInput");
            $("#control_2").addClass("CellInput_");   
        });

//input control_3
    $("#control_3").click(function() {
            $("#control_3").addClass("CellInput");
            $("#control_3").removeClass("CellInput_");
        }); 
            
        $("#control_3").focusout(function() {
            $("#control_3").removeClass("CellInput");
            $("#control_3").addClass("CellInput_");   
        });
```

I've tried to shorten it like below, but still not working or maybe I missed something..

```
$("#control_1 #control_2 #control_3").click(function() {
        $(this).addClass("CellInput");
        $(this).removeClass("CellInput_");
    }); 
        
    $("#control_1 #control_2 #control_3").focusout(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("CellInput");
        $(this).addClass("CellInput_");   
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want

```
$("#control_1,#control_2,#control_3")
```

since `$("#control_1 #control_2 #control_3")` would match a `control_3` element within a `control_2` element within a `control_1` element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#control_1, #control_2, #control_3").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("CellInput");
});

$("#control_1, #control_2, #control_3").focusout(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("CellInput"); 
});
```

Comment: There was also another class `Cellinput_`

Comment: Than add `$(this).toggleClass("CellInput_");`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding [AKX answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65166734/4700922) you can even make it shorter if there are more than 3 elements:

```
$('[id^=control_]').click({
//blah
})
```

this selects all elements which their ID starts with `control_`